# Magento 2 How to get all products from a non anchor parent category and its subcategories

Tags: magento-2.1, products, category-products, category-tree

I want to display all products from a non anchor parent category and its subcategories. My categories are non anchor.

http://i.prntscr.com/NOZYKxj4Sh2S2tw1yHjyLQ.png

Answer (score 2):

Magento's architecture is set in such a way that, the categories having the attribute code `is_anchor` value set to 0, will not display products in that particular category. In order to display the products, either you have to change the display setting of all non anchor categories to yes, or update the database table entries.

You can do this from the `Admin => CATALOG => Catagories => Display Setting` and set `Anchor` to `Yes` or make the following changes in the database table entries.

1) Get the `attribute_id` from `eav_attribute` table where the `attribute_code` is `is_anchor`. In my case, it is 54.

2) Update the `value` field from the table `catalog_category_entity_int` to 1,  where the `attribute_id` is the one which you got from the previous query.

3) Run the reindex

Now check your categories.